# How to add a node based on a keyword in R using XML package

Tags: r, xml

Below is sample xml code to show the structure of my xml code. And I have XML file names to loop through and if I find author IDs matching those already in the below code, I would like to add a new node under the same author, not at the end of the document. The matching string can be found by searching through file names such as: *bk110_abcd991992_588966_Gambardella_20100514.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
    <books>
       <book>
          <authorid>588966</authorid>
          <bookid>bk101</bookid>
          <author>Gambardella</author>
          <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
          <genre>Computer</genre>
          <price>44.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
          <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
       </book>
    </books>
    <books>
       <book>
          <authorid>985371</authorid>
          <bookid>bk102</bookid>
          <author>Ralls</author>
          <title>Midnight Rain</title>
          <genre>Fantasy</genre>
          <price>5.99</price>
          <publish_date>2000-12-18</publish_date>
          <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies</description>
       </book>
    </books>
</catalog>
```

As seen in the xml file name above (bk110_abcd991992_588966_Gambardella_20100514.xml), author ID: 588966 already exists in our code, thus I would like to add a *book* node for Gambardella. Please don't worry about the looping part through multiple file names, just show me how to find that string (authorID) and how to add a new node and the new code should look like the following. I appreciate your help

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
    <books>
       <book>
          <authorid>588966</authorid>
          <bookid>bk101</bookid>
          <author>Gambardella</author>
          <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
          <genre>Computer</genre>
          <price>44.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
          <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
       </book>
       <book>
          <authorid>588966</authorid>
          <bookid>bk110</bookid>
          <author>Gambardella</author>
          <title>Text Mining</title>
          <genre>Computer</genre>
          <price>14.95</price>
          <publish_date>2010-05-14</publish_date>
          <description>Gaining Insight from text data</description>
        </book>
    </books>
    <books>
       <book>
          <authorid>985371</authorid>
          <bookid>bk102</bookid>
          <author>Ralls</author>
          <title>Midnight Rain</title>
          <genre>Fantasy</genre>
          <price>5.99</price>
          <publish_date>2000-12-18</publish_date>
          <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies</description>
       </book>
    </books>
</catalog>
```

Comment: Please post your attempted code using `XML` package so we can help you get to finish line and help in your learning curve. If you did not start, please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) for an implementation and give it an earnest try.

Comment: Where is the content to fill in the new `book` node? Please include that data if it derives from a different XML or other source. There are ways to combine XML data.

Comment: @Parfait thanks for your feedback. The code I have using XML package accomplishes other tasks, not the one described in this post. But I'm also not leaning towards one package or the other. I can use either package as long as it accomplishes what I need. As for the second part of your question, the data is derived from the file name. I didn't include all info in the file name for simplicity. So ultimately I want to extract data elements from the file name and use them to construct a node which I will then insert into the master xml file above

Comment: @Parfait the full file name would look something like this: bk110_14.95_588966_Gambardella_Text-Mining_Computer_Gaining-Insight-from-text-data_20100514.xml. I don't care about what's inside, I'm only interested in the file name where I need to find the authorID and if it already exists, I add the node under the same author

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use the `xml2` package here, which is easier to use in a pipe format. Manually adding all the xml fields can be a little laborious, so you might want to try creating a little wrapper function around this.

Starting by loading in the necessary packages, we can read, modify and save the xml like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2)

read_xml('bk110_abcd991992_588966_Gambardella_20100514.xml') %>%
  xml_find_first('//authorid[.=588966]/parent::book/parent::books') %>%
  xml_add_child('book') %>%
    xml_add_child('authorid') %>% xml_set_text("588966") %>%
    xml_add_sibling('bookid') %>% xml_set_text('bk110') %>%
    xml_add_sibling('author') %>% xml_set_text('Gambardella') %>%
    xml_add_sibling('title')  %>% xml_set_text('Text Mining') %>%
    xml_add_sibling('genre')  %>% xml_set_text('Computer') %>%
    xml_add_sibling('price')  %>% xml_set_text('14.95') %>%
    xml_add_sibling('publish_date') %>% xml_set_text('2010-05-14') %>%
    xml_add_sibling('description') %>% 
     xml_set_text('Gaining insight from text data') %>%
  xml_root() %>%
  write_xml('updated_file.xml')
```

Now we have

**updated_file.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <books>
    <book>
      <authorid>588966</authorid>
      <bookid>bk101</bookid>
      <author>Gambardella</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
    </book>
    <book>
      <authorid>588966</authorid>
      <bookid>bk110</bookid>
      <author>Gambardella</author>
      <title>Text Mining</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>14.95</price>
      <publish_date>2010-05-14</publish_date>
      <description>Gaining insight from text data</description>
    </book>
  </books>
  <books>
    <book>
      <authorid>985371</authorid>
      <bookid>bk102</bookid>
      <author>Ralls</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.99</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-18</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies</description>
    </book>
  </books>
</catalog>
```

Comment: I'd like to clarify. The information needed to construct a new node is derived from a file name. A file that's completely different from the one where we are inserting the new node. The complete file name would look like this: bk110_14.95_588966_Gambardella_Text-Mining_Computer_Gaining-Insight-from-text-data_20100514.xml. I'm only interested in the file name where I need to find the authorID and if it already exists, I add the node under the same author as described above. And thanks so much for your answer, also as you suggested, I think xml2 will be cleaner for tidyverse style of programming